# Empty folder inside docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to understand docker. I took examples from [docker-compose-starter](https://github.com/paralect/docker-compose-starter) and adapted it to my app but couldn't find files inside container. Help me please to solve this problem.

I have a server built on nodeJS. Here is a structure of project folders:

```
my_home_dir  
.. web_draw_room
.... bin
...... init.sh
.... docker
...... images
........ server
.......... Dockerfile
...... docker-compose.yml
.... server
...... app.js
...... package.json
```

Here is a Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7.10.0
EXPOSE 8000
ENV NODE_ENV=development
WORKDIR /var/www/web-draw-room/server
CMD npm install
```

Here is a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    hostname: server
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: ~/web-draw-room/docker/images/server
    volumes:
      - "~/web-draw-room/server:/var/www/web-draw-room/server"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

And here is an init.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/web-draw-room/docker
docker-compose up --build "server"
```

I see that directory /var/www/web-draw-room/server exists inside container but it doesn't contain files.
Thanks.

Comment: docker-compose may not like the `~` in the yml file? Try an absolute path or a path relative to your build context.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.